# Is redefinition of a variable valid inside loops?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have encountered the following *binarySearch* program

```cpp
int binarySearch(int a[],int b, int c)
{
    int start=0,end=b-1;
    while(start<=end)
    {
        int mid=start+(end-start)/2;
        if(a[mid]==c)
            return mid;
        else if(a[mid]>c)
            end=mid-1;
        else
            start=mid+1;
    }
    if(start>end)
        return -1;
}
```

in which *mid* variable is initialized in the loop which will be executed if the condition *start<=end* becomes true.

I am new to programming and i have learnt that **redefinition of variable is not valid in C**. But i have encountered ***binarySearch*** program in which loop will be executed when *start<=end* will be true and will be initializing an int variable named *mid* again and again till the condition will be true and thus redefinition will take place. I want to know *"are redefinition valid inside loops?"* or something else i am missing.

Comment: What do you mean "redefinition"? Here you're *reassigning*. The `mid` variable is very tightly scoped, and when it falls out of scope it *goes away*.

Comment: Think of each iteration of the code as being ran in its own function.  Every function is allowed to declare variables that have the same name as variables in other functions.

Comment: Each `mid` is a new `mid`. You are not redefining it.

Comment: Tip: If you `return` in an `if` for sure, the `else` is redundant and just adds unnecessary indentation. Unless you don't indent, in which case your code is just a mess.

Comment: **Redefinition** is when a symbol name is defined two or more times in the same scope.  In the scope of your `while` loop, `mid` is defined once.

Answer (score 4):

A variable itself is a compile-time concept, it's a label in the source code, a name  which refers to an actual object that will exist at runtime.

Since `int mid` is only spelled once in your code, there's no redefinition. Even if it was spelled multiple times, if the variables are in different places, it can be legal (the variables will shadow one another):

```
int a = 1;

int main()
{
    std::cout << a << '\n'; // 1

    int a = 2;

    if (true)
    {
        int a = 3;
        std::cout << a << '\n'; // 3
    }

    std::cout << a << '\n'; // 2
}
```

Comment: Not sure it is the answer waited for. Looks like OP want to know if the variable mid is defined each time the block is executed during the looping.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, they expected an error because this is supposedly "repeated definition". This means they're confusing variables and their definitions (which is a compile-time concept) with objects and their lifetimes and repeated execution of loops (which are runtime concepts).